# Hook not receiving updated value when parent component is memoized

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Suppose the following:

```
import * as React from "react";

const useMyHook = ({ element }: { element: HTMLElement | null }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {
      console.log("element in hook", element);
    }
  }, [element]);
};

const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log("element in parent", ref.current);
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  useMyHook({ element: ref.current });

  return <div ref={ref}>my content</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent />;
}
```

My issue here is that `element in hook` is never printed to the console. I managed to get it to work by removing `React.memo`, but I'm wondering why this is happening and how, if possible, I can get this work while still using `React.memo`?

I know that refs don't rerender the component, however my hook checks for changes in a `useEffect`, so I'm a little confused as to why it behaves like that.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  // works fine like this
};
```

Comment: This is due to React.memo but you can handle this by wrapping your component and then pass the element as a prop to MyComponent. this way, it will trigger a re-render of MyComponent when element changes

Answer (score 1):

In your example the `ref` gets its value when the div gets mounted.

```
<div ref={ref}>my content</div>
```

This will assign the value to the `ref`, but your `useMyHook` runs before that happens. `{ element: ref.current }` element becomes null. It is true that `useEffect` will call after the render, but the value that is passed to `element` is **passed by value**, **not by reference**. This is the main reason your useEffect inside the component runs as expected, but the useEffect in your hook does not.

If you do:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const element = ref.current  // assign the value of the ref.current
   // in the first render its null, so element = null

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {  // since it is null, it does not pass the condition
      console.log("element in parent", ref.current);
    }
  }, [element]);  // it is null in the first render

  return <div ref={ref}>my content</div>;
});
```

This wont work either.

The way you can fix this is by using the `ref prop` as callback, instead of the result of `useRef()`.

```
<div ref={useCallback((node) => console.log(node), [])}>my content</div>;
```

This callback will be called when the div mounts. The node will be the div itself as `HTMLDivElement`

About the `React.memo` thing, probably something else causes an extra render and that makes `{ element: ref.current }` to give the current value of the `div` that it had from the previous render.

Comment: Another solution would be to pass the reference directly instead of the value to your hook `useMyHook`.

---> https://playcode.io/1781320

Comment: That is true, but I wouldn't recommend that. It will enforce ```useMyHook``` to always accept a ref, instead of the element itself. Also if you decide to pass that ref to something else, while the component is already mounted, it won't trigger the ```useEffect```. It is hard to track a ref value as a dependency, since it will not cause a rerender.

Comment: Good catch!  Generally adding a `useEffect` on a element is not something I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As Oktay Yuzcan said, the `element` is passed by value to your hook `useMyHook`. And because of `useMemo` your hook is not rerender so it is executed with the value of `element` before it is actually set.

An other way to fix your issue is to provide the reference directly to your hook `useMyHook` instead of the value.

```
import * as React from "react";

const useMyHook = ({ element }: { element: RefObject>HTMLElement | null> }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (element.current) {
      console.log("element in hook", element.current);
    }
  }, [element.current]);
};

const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log("element in parent", ref.current);
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  useMyHook({ element: ref }); // <-- provide directly the reference

  return <div ref={ref}>my content</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent />;
}
```

With this way, your hook will receive always the up to date version of `element.current`.

Comment: This is why I wouldn't recommend this approach. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzp3rr?file=src%2FApp.js. We can change the element that ref is assigned to, but the useEffect wont trigger

Answer (score -1):

The reason why "element in hook" is not printed to the console when using React.memo is because React.memo is a higher-order component that only re-renders the component if its props have changed.

so you have to use `useCallback` to memorize the `useMyhook`

the code would be:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const useMyHook = React.useCallback(({ element }: { element: HTMLElement | null }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {
      console.log("element in hook", element);
    }
  }, [element]);
}, []); // Empty dependency array as useMyHook does not depend on any external variables

const MyComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log("element in parent", ref.current);
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  useMyHook({ element: ref.current });

  return <div ref={ref}>my content</div>;
});

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent />;
}
```